Can't use service account on emulator
I'm working on a project using React and Firebase. I'm working with Firebase emulator and I want to get the getDownloadURL out of a an image thats uploaded to Firebase storage so that i can add it to a corresponding image document. I tried using this code which is inside an onFinalize cloud function:
const newFile = admin
          .storage()
          .bucket(object.bucket)
          .file(object.name);
        const config = { action: "read", expires: "01-01-2035" };
        const downloadURLs = await newFile.getSignedUrl(config);
        const downloadURL = downloadURLs[0];

const images = firestore.collection("images");

return images.add({
          imageURL: imageLink,
          downloadURL: downloadURL,
        });


I get the error:

Cannot sign data without client_email.

I learnt that this means i need a service account and then i created one, placed the file in my functions folder and ran the following code:
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="functions/serviceAccount.json"           
firebase emulators:start --project=demo-project

and i got the following error:

⚠  functions: Failed to initialize and load triggers. This shouldn't happen: Failed to read credentials from file functions/serviceAccount.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'functions/serviceAccount.json'

I then went on to use the service account thats specified in my Firebase settings page, placed it in my environment variables and ran the functions like so...
initializeApp({
        serviceAccountId: "demo-serviceAccount",
        apiKey: "demo-key",
        authDomain: "demo-domain",
        projectId: "demo-project",
        storageBucket: "demo-project.appspot.com",
        appId: "demo-appId",
        messagingSenderId: "demo-id",
        measurementId: "demo-measurementId",
      })

And this didn't work:

Request to function failed: Error: socket hang up
This apparently is a Mac issue but when i applied the fix, nothing changed.

I've seen some comments mention that .json service accounts are not safe. What is best for an emulator?
Any help would be appreciated.

You don't need a service account with the emulators.  Have you read the documentation for Firestore and Cloud Storage?

I have read through them and understand that a service account is not necessary but why do i still get errors even when i'm not using a service account?

I don't know.  If you think the errors are a result of the emulator not functioning correctly, you should file an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub.  Or better yet, submit a PR to fix it yourself.  In the meantime, just follow what the documentation says.

@DougStevenson, turns out you do need a service account for certain thing in the emulator. According to these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Is that's what you're trying to do? "If you want your functions tests to interact with Google APIs or other Firebase APIs via the Firebase Admin SDK, you may need to set up admin credentials."
